# Kafka/Flink integration problems with map function

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm running a simple script in scala with Apache Flink. 
I read the data from an Apache Kafka producer. This is my code.

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}

object App {

  def main(args : Array[String]) {

case class Sensor2(sensor_name: String, start_date: String, end_date: String, data: String, stt: Int)

val properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
    val consumer1 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String]("topics1", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
   val stream1 = env
   .addSource(consumer1)
   .flatMap(raw => JsonMethods.parse(raw).toOption)

   env.execute()

 }

}
```

I get a "missing parameter type" error on the flatMap (but is the same error I get when I try to use other functions, as map or filter).
I don't know ho to solve that. 
Any help?

LF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the scala API version of `StreamExecutionEnvironment`.

Change your imports to:

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods
```

Comment: Thank you. This resolved the missing parameters type error.

Comment: In order to parse the DataStream[String] coming from Kafka into a DataStream[Sensor2] class I had to make some modification to the code. The working code is:
`val consumer1 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String]("topics1", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
       val stream1 = env
       .addSource(consumer1)
       
       
       val s1 = stream1.map { x => {
         implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
         JsonMethods.parse(x).extract[Sensor2]
         }
       }`